# Stripe charge upfront for metered package

Tags: stripe-payments

We are a SaaS company that charges users for duration of audio that gets processed by our platform. We charge $15 for 1 hour of audio and we don't have a flat subscription fee.
We offer pay-as-you-go method, for example, a user uploads an audio with 1.5 hour duration and we charge `$15 * 1.5` upfront.
We would like to offer packages, like *"Buy 100 hours and get a 15% discount"*.
In case a user picks a package we would like the following things to happen:

- user gets charged **upfont** for `$12.75 * 100 = $1275`
- as user keeps spending "package hours" we **report usage** to stripe
- when user **runs out** of package - package is renewed and we **charge** them **again**
- [optionally] we charge user for a new package when they have X% of package usage remaining

How should we approach this in terms of integration with stripe?
I looked through Stripe docs and didn't find an scenario for this use case.
Is it possible to use metered usage and subscriptions for that or should we implement the whole package handling logic on our side?

Answer (score 2):

A Stripe developers discord moderator replied to me with this:

I think that doing this via one-off payments and tracking usage yourself is the way to achieve this at the moment. Metered billing still expects to charge the user for their usage at regular intervals, it is more for charging a user for X minutes one month and then Y minutes the next, I don't think there is a good way to credit your user and trigger another full payment as soon as the credit is up